# How do I change the fragment that is showing next

Tags: java, android

I took the tab activity start and took the tabs out of the code and the floating button. I created a new fragment to replace the placeholder one. I just don't understand how to get it to swipe to a different fragment then the replacement placeholder one. Not sure if I should continue this or try to do a different viewpager. Any help in what to change, where to learn this particular thing, or any other help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to program an app for my union and bring it closer to being modern. Thank you.

```
package myapp.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public static class fragment_contact extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public fragment_contact() {
        }

        public static fragment_contact newInstance(int i) {
            fragment_contact fragment = new fragment_contact();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
            return rootView;
       }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public fragment_contact getItem(int i) {
            return new fragment_contact();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 11;
        }
      }
    }
```